# Matrix of constrained sums using R

Tags: matrix, r

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252999/constrained-sum-of-product-binomial-coefficients/253093#253093), I asked a question regarding how to create a matrix of integers where elements in each row satisfy a particular property.

The notation in the original post is a bit cumbersome so I will try to explain the question in a nutshell. I have a vector of integers `cvec`, which has length `l-1`, and I enumerate all the possibilities in a matrix such that every integer in each of the `l` columns is less than or equal to `cvec[1]` (first three lines of code). Then I iteratively reduce that large set possibilities into a smaller matrix, such that for a given row:

1. Consecutive elements taken 2,3,...l-1 at a time must be no larger than `cvec[2]`, `cvec[3]`, ..., `cvec[l-1]`, respectively
2. The total sum of the `l` elements is equal to `x`.

By first subsetting `mat` to only those rows with sum `x`, and then running the nested for loops, I've been able to reduce the runtime by over 1/10th. For the above example, it now runs `7.8 seconds`. However, I still think this could be faster if I somehow eliminate the nested loops. Any suggestions?

```
valid.counts2 <- function(x,l,cvec){
  #l>1
  vec = seq(from=0,to=cvec[1])
  lst = lapply(numeric(l), function(i) vec)
  mat = as.matrix(expand.grid(lst))
  mat = mat[which(rowSums(mat)==x),]

  if(l>2){
    #k=1 is redundant since all must be less than or equal to cvec[1]
    for (k in seq(from=2, to=l-1)){
      row.indx = NULL
      for (r in seq(l-k+1)){
        #pick out the index of the row(s) that satisfy constraint
        row.indx = which(rowSums(mat[,r:(r+k-1),drop=FALSE])<=cvec[k])
        #filter rows of mat
        mat = mat[unique(row.indx),]
      }
    }
  }
  return(mat) 
}
```

Comment: Replace `==` by `%in%` so you can now use a whole vector like `x=seq(from=148,to=155)` as input. For the output, you could `return(table(rowSums(mat))` if all you care about is the number of solutions. Also, your use of `unique()` is useless and you do not need to initalize `row.indx = NULL`.

Comment: Thank you! I do care about what the solutions are. I'm trying to get the entire functionality to milliseconds so that simulations are more feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a top-down (very memory intensive) approach, I would recommend a somewhat bottom-up approach, where you add one column at a time then do the reductions, add another column, etc. Try this:

```
expand.mat <- function(mat, vec) {
   out <- matrix(0L, nrow = nrow(mat) * length(vec),
                     ncol = ncol(mat) + 1)
   for (i in 1:ncol(mat)) out[, i] <- mat[, i]
   out[, ncol(mat) + 1] <- rep(vec, each = nrow(mat))
   return(out)
}

valid.counts3 <- function(x, cvec) {
   l   <-  length(cvec) + 1
   vec <- seq(from = 0, to = cvec[1])
   mat <- matrix(vec, ncol = 1)

   for (j in 2:l) {

      mat  <- expand.mat(mat, vec)
      rsum <- rowSums(mat)
      mat  <- mat[rsum <= x & rsum + cvec[1] * (l - j) >= x, ]

      for (i in 1:(j-1)) {
         k <- j - i + 1
         if (k == l) next
         rsum <- rowSums(mat[, i:j])
         mat  <- mat[rsum <= cvec[k], ]
      }
   }

   return(mat)
}

system.time({
   res <- valid.counts3(x = 148, cvec = c(36, 67, 92, 119))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.279   0.036   0.319
```

**Edit**: And to handle a vector of `x` as input, make these slight changes. It will return a list of matrices.

```
valid.counts3 <- function(x, cvec) {
   l   <-  length(cvec) + 1
   vec <- seq(from = 0, to = cvec[1])
   mat <- matrix(vec, ncol = 1)

   for (j in 2:l) {

      mat  <- expand.mat(mat, vec)
      rsum <- rowSums(mat)
      mat  <- mat[rsum <= max(x) & rsum + cvec[1] * (l - j) >= min(x), ]

      for (i in 1:(j-1)) {
         k <- j - i + 1
         if (k == l) next
         rsum <- rowSums(mat[, i:j])
         mat  <- mat[rsum <= cvec[k], ]
      }
   }

   mat <- mat[rowSums(mat) %in% x, ]
   idx <- split(seq(nrow(mat)), rowSums(mat))
   return(lapply(idx, function(i, x) x[i, ], mat))
}

system.time({
   res <- valid.counts3(x = seq(from = 148, to = 155), cvec = c(36, 67, 92, 119))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.333   0.048   0.381 

sapply(res, nrow)
#  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155 
# 8649 5776 3600 2025 1024  441  144   25
```